# how do I save files directly to the cloud from ubuntu?

Tags: google-drive

I have a google drive account that I got with my chromebook but I don't know how to back up my files from my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Google has not released a dedicated Drive plug-in for Linux like they did for Windows and Mac. So have to use a cloud-service that does support Linux like dropbox or use and third party client for Google drive.

I can't say which program is best for needs but here is an article that describes some options. [The article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/google-drive-clients-linux/)